# Whether to use OpenFeint

Tags: android, openfeint

Any pointers why I should use OpenFeint for my android project? I have gone through their website and others. I didn't see why OpenFeint should be my choice. May be I overlooked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the project a little bit. It's hard to give pointers about a complete mystery.

Comment: Kind of math quiz where users can submit score and compare with others. It is a light-weight project. I don't want unnecessary load but I want to be a robust system.

Comment: OpenFeint certainly provides some nice options for game developers, such as leaderboards and achievements, and what's best in it, you don't need to implement your own service of synchronizing a players achievements with your server, you don't need to have a server yourself. OpenFeint does it all for you. Now it's your choice whether to use these features or not.

Comment: thz, guys. Hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will not be relevant, as I've used OpenFeint for iOS, but each time we have to do anything in this, the assumption of team is 'Gosh, it's 7 lines of code'. Then it takes 2 days to actually implement this.

Code is badly designed, doc's was sometime ago still not ready, or hidden so deep that we could not find it. Now there is some doxygen doc, it's a bit better.

But still, each time we work with it 'black magic' that comes with this code.

This is for iOS. Java for me is much more elegant and error prone language, so maybe Android version looks nicer.

P.S: I've just asked my Java guys for OF and they said: "It works, but there's no documentation". So maybe in fact it's bit better than for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

We tried using OpenFeint on Android and found that it was incredibly lacking compared to their iOS offering (slow, clunky, missing features, etc).  If you're still looking, check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com), which was built specifically as a more Android focused replacement for OpenFeint.